# need help for imacros code to request first 25 "answer request" from writer on quora

Tags: imacros

i am new to imacros...

i have tried to record the imacros to request an answer from the writer but I think it's dynamically changing the pos and values...

so, looking for a way to do this...

here is the code that I have recorded

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
TAG POS=12 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=2 TYPE=PATH ATTR=STROKE-LINECAP:round&&TXT:
TAG POS=3 TYPE=CIRCLE ATTR=CX:12&&CY:12&&R:9&&TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:__w2_wx4nZclL125_button
TAG POS=23 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=25 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:__w2_wx4nZclL134_button
TAG POS=29 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=31 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:__w2_wOt2sXY49_button
TAG POS=35 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:__w2_wJ28TPOd2_list_item
TAG POS=37 TYPE=SVG ATTR=TXT:
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:__w2_wDJBb2oM9_button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:__w2_wx4nZclL2_submit
```

Comment: + Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum with more Info (and better Quality): FCI mentioned + Screenshots and more Explanation about the Scenario... (And Solution/"Way to go" provided...): https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=30373